# How to set auto import for Kotlin in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin

I can only find auto import options for XML, Java and C/C++ in preferences, but how can I make auto import work for Kotlin in Android Studio?

[image]

**update:**
Most of the time, import statement is added automatically. But unused import statement never get cleared automatically when deleting codes.

Answer (score 1):

Auto Import is always on for Kotlin which is why you don't see the option.

If it isn't working the way you expect then you might create an issue in [JetBrains Bug & Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues)r.